# Can progressive (to be +verbing ) be used to indicate the importance of an action or an event?

Tags: progressive-aspect

> We are very pleased **to be releasing** this new MIDNITE SNAXXX
>   record! It is a classic two song single, same recording session as the
>   single that was released on Goodbye Boozy Records a couple of months
>   ago.

Why **to be releasing**? Because when this ad was written, the record had been already finished and pressed and was in the shop, so the action of releasing was completed.

Is it to express the importance of the release, that is a record not to miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A record release is not necessarily a single day event. The company may have an initial release date, which is usually the first day that retail customers can buy the record. Sometimes the record may also be able to be ordered in prior to the release date, but it will not be delivered prior to the release date.

However, once the release date has passed, the release process may continue to roll out. For example, some retail outlets may place a small initial order for sale at the release date, then wait to see how well those records sell before making a decision regarding placing a larger order a few days or weeks later.

So the release period may extend for several weeks, or for a really popular record, several months. During this period the company can legitimately say that they are 'pleased to be releasing' the record. Eventually, however, the company will move into a post-release phase, and will then start to talk about 'being please to have released' the record.